# xCode: Passing a Label text into a custom added subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, properties, pass-data

I have rewritten this to try and make it more descriptive with more code hopefully:

I have set up a separate `UIView` class called: pageTitleView code below:
header file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface pageTitleView : UIView
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pageTitle;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *subTitle;
 @end
```

The M File:

```
 @implementation pageTitleView

   @synthesize pageTitle;
   @synthesize subTitle;

  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

     pageTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,labelPosY,300,20)];
     pageTitle.textColor = txtColour;
     pageTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     pageTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     pageTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
     // pageTitle.text to be set by parent view
    [self addSubview:pageTitle];
  }
```

With in my parent view controller I have the following:

The Header File:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface UsingThisGuide : UIViewController

     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *PageTitleBlock;
     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *dispalyPageContent;
     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *FooterBar;

   @end
```

In the M file i have the following:

```
  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
  #import "pageTitleView.h"
  #import "MyFirstView.h"

  @interface MyFirstView ()

  @end

  @implementation MyFirstView {
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
         if (self) {
          // Custom initialization
          }
        return self;
     }
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

      _PageTitleBlock = [[pageTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
      _PageTitleBlock.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

      _PageTitleBlock.pageTitle.text = @"This should work but not";

      [self.view addSubview:_PageTitleBlock];
      [super viewDidLoad];
    }

 @end
```

No what i want to do is set the `pageTitle.text` from the `pageTitleView` class via its parent controller `MyFirstView` using something like `_PageTitleBlock.pageTitle.text=` but this is the error i am getting:

```
  Property 'pageTitle' not found on object of type 'UIView *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is that you are declaring your property called `PageTitleBlock` of type **`UIView`** in `UsingThisGuide`, but then call `pageTitle` which is declared in the class `pageTitleView`. The compiler doesn't trust this.

Change the type of `PageTitleBlock` from `UIView` to `pageTitleView` and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for this a little giggle of things and that worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that easily, for example, using `properties`.

1. In header file of `TitleBlock` (or `pageTitleView`) class in `@interface` section before `@end` you should define property:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel pageTitle;
   ```

   or for ARC-projects

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel pageTitle;
   ```
2. In parent view controller you should initiate `_PageTitleBlock` with **frame**:

   ```
   _PageTitleBlock = [[pageTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)]; // specify needed frame
   // and add it to root view:
   [self.view addSubview:_PageTitleBlock];
   ```
3. Now you could access `pageTitle` property:

   ```
   _PageTitleBlock.pageTitle.text = @"Text of page title label";
   ```

Hope it will help you.

P.S. For class names it is better to use сapitalized names, i.e., `PageTitleView` rather then `pageTitleView`.

Comment: i have most of the above and then I have tried the last bit but getting the error a the _PageTitleBlock.pageTitle.text = @"Text of page title label"; section getting the following error Property 'pageTitle' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: Is `_PageTitleBlock` instance of class with that property?

Comment: +1 Nekto is right. By using properties you can expose the label in order to modify it. One other (uglier) way to achieve it would be to grab the label from the `subviews` array: `UILabel *pageTitle = [[_PageTitleBlock subViews] lastObject];`

Comment: @SimonDavies do you understand Object-Oriented Programming?

Comment: yes i do understand OOP i have updated the question with more of the code for understanding, hopt this helps, sorry

Comment: @SimonDavies you really didn't give chance for me to answer and accepted other answer when it become more clearly what you wanted? Guy, I won't answer on any of your questions.

Comment: @Nekto apologies but am working on this and like yours tried the answer, again apologies that is all I can offer